# WinForms: Generic forms don't open anymore in designer in .NET 7

Tags: winforms, generics, .net-core, base-class

In order to be sure that it's .NET 7 (.NET Core) related, I created a project with .NET 4.7.2 with a generic base form and a derived one. Both can be opened and are shown properly. Only in .NET 7 it's not working anymore. When trying to open the base form I get

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.

When trying to open the derived form I get

> Cannot create an instance of WinFormsApp2.Form1`1[TEntity] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Why is that, just in .NET Core?

I found something about "UseLegacyPathHandling" which I added to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config:

```
<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false" />
```

But that didn't help.

Comment: I'm surprised generic `Form` subclasses ever worked at all in the designer, honestly. Anyway, a possible workaround is to subclass `WinFormsApp2.Form1<TEntity>` with a _closed_ generic type, e.g. `class DesignerFormWorkaround : Form1<SomeConcreteEntityHere>` - and then the designer _should_ work  - that said, a _generic form_ class just seems like a bad idea anyway considering how the rest of the WinForms tooling and infrastructure works.

Comment: @Dai Yes, it did. I spent quite some time for that in .NET Framework but now as we had to switch to .NET it looks like a step backwards. :|

Comment: Can you upload your test code to github or something? I'd really like to see your 4.7.2 project too.

Comment: @Dai https://github.com/IngoBleile/WinFormsGenericBaseForm